# Freeglut: Functions missing

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm currently learning OpenGL (in class) and we're using freeglut 2.8.2, which works just fine (using Visual Studio 2012). As an additional learning resource I'm reading the "OpenGL Superbible, 5h Edition". However, I've noticed that there are some functions that aren't available using the freeglut library.

For example, gluGenerateMipmap or setting anisotropic filtering doesn't work:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, fLargest);
void glGenerateMipmap(GLenum target);
```

It simply does not know these functions (glTexParameterf is known, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT is not). I've googled a bit but didn't really find anything. And since glGenerateMipmap seems to belong to the standard openGL Library (and not glu/glut), it should be available (I hope).

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glGenerateMipmap` is an extension, unless you are using OpenGL 3 or above (I think). You probably want to use a library like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to load it.

See [OpenGL Extensions](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/extensions/) for more information about extensions in OpenGL. Many things that were extensions in 2.x were promoted to the core API in versions 3 and 4, but unless you upgrade to those versions, you'll have to use an extension loading library (or do it yourself, which is not really that fun or worthwhile).